# For what $p$, $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x^{3p})}{(x+x^3)^{4p}arctg\sqrt{x}}$ converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have to see for what values of $p$ the following integral converges. $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x^{3p})}{(x+x^3)^{4p}arctg\sqrt{x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+x^{3p})}{(x+x^3)^{4p}arctg\sqrt{x}} + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x^{3p})}{(x+x^3)^{4p}arctg\sqrt{x}}$$ So the first part is easy to estimate because it's convergent with $$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{p+\frac{1}{2}}}$$, so here $p<\frac{1}{2}$.But with the second part I have no idea what to do apart from $arctg\sqrt{x}$ being bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Any  ideas and solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the integrand with (a multiple of) $\ln(x)/x^{12p}$?

Comment: @GregMartin Hmm i see what you mean , of course it's not that easy to see the $\ln(x)$ part. So does that mean that $\ln(x)/x^{12p}\sim 1/x^{12p}$ ?

Comment: No, that's definitely false (their quotient is $\ln x$, which doesn't tend to $1$). However, it turns out that they converge/diverge for the same value of $p$: the $\ln x$ is so mild that it doesn't change the answer. (That requires proof of course.)

Comment: @GregMartin Well this is what I meant that for large enough $x$,$\ln(x)$ tends to infinity a lot slower than $x^{12p}$. So is the final answer $p \in (\frac{1}{12};\frac{1}{2})$?